# How to stop jQuery from matching multiple elements

Tags: jquery, html, class, hover

I am trying to create a rollover effect with jQUery. I have similar things, however because I am trying to do a mouseover with a an object that has a link in it I am having problems.

I have a level-2 nav bar. The placeholder's are table cells (bad I know - but it's already done this way). I want to change the background from white (#FFF) to dark grey (#999). I also want to change the text from dark grey to white.

Since the text is a link, I have to specify a class within the link  tag to ensure that it is dark grey without an underline and doesn't default to the blue, underlined text.

The code I have written causes all the links of class="subLink" to change to being white from grey when anyone of them is "hovered over". I only want this to happen for the particular item in question - that is the background should become grey and the link should become white.

HTML and jQuery are below:-

```
<td class="subMenuTD"><a href="newsletter.html" class="subLink">Newsletter</a></td>
<td class="subMenuTD"><a href="news_archive.html" class="subLink">News Archive</a></td>
<td class="subMenuTD"><a href="events.html">Events</a></td>
```

---

```
$(".subMenuTD").hover(
                  function() { 
                     $(this).addClass("subMenuTDActive");
                     $(".subLink").addClass("subLink-white");
                  },
                  function() {      
                     $(this).removeClass("subMenuTDActive");
                     $(".subLink").removeClass("subLink-white");
          }
               );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a context parameter to the $() function.

`$(".subLink")` --> `$(".subLink", this)` will make jQuery only match ".subLink"s that are children of the given context element.

Answer (score 2):

You can make this even simpler by not adding the class to the link, since you are already adding a class to the parent td, and can thus target the link by using CSS:

**Code before**

```
$(".subMenuTD").hover(                       
  function() {
     $(this).addClass("subMenuTDActive");                                
     $(".subLink").addClass("subLink-white");
  },
  function() {
     $(this).removeClass("subMenuTDActive");                                
     $(".subLink").removeClass("subLink-white");
  }
);
```

**Code after**

```
$(".subMenuTD").hover(                       
  function() {
     $(this).addClass("subMenuTDActive");     
  },
  function() {
     $(this).removeClass("subMenuTDActive");    
  }
);
```

**New CSS rule**

```
.subMenuTDActive .subLink {
   /* Add hover link styling here */
}
```

This will work because ".subMenuTDActive .subLink" has a higher specitivity than ".subLink", and will thus override the ".subLink" rule.

Answer (score 1):

I'm with drthomas. Why on earth are you using javascript at all when you can just use css?

```
 .subMenuTD:hover {
                   background-color: #ccc;
                   }

 .subLink:hover {
                 color: #fff;
                 }
```

Or even better (me thinks), get rid of styling the td elements that you shouldn't have and ought to be working on removing, set the links as display:block, and then you can declare the hover style under one element:

```
 .subLink {
          display: block;
          }

  .subLink:hover {
                 background-color: #ccc;
                 color: #fff;
                 }
```

And unless you have no control over the html or you have something mission-critical that relies on the markup staying the same, "it's already using tables, i know, sue me" is a really poor excuse. Here is your sub-menu, sans table:

```
<ul class="subMenu">
<li><a href="newsletter.html">Newsletter</a></li>
<li><a href="news_archive.html">News Archive</a></li>
<li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
</ul>
```

That took about 30 seconds. Now here is the CSS for the navbar/rollover:

```
 .subMenu li {
          display: inline;
          list-style: none;
          }

  .subMenu a {
          color: #000;
          background-color: #fff;
          text-decoration: none;
          display: block;
          }

   .subMenu a:hover {
          color: #fff;
          background-color: #ccc;
          }
```

That took maybe a minute more, because I had to make it look pretty.

I'm not trying to be a bully or come down on you, but non-semantic code is not something that should be encouraged, and if you are looking for help with something, I wouldn't feel right giving it knowing it was going to be used on a site that wasn't compliant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AKX's solution, or:

```
$(".subMenuTD").hover(
                    function() { 
                            $(this)
                               .addClass("subMenuTDActive")
                               .children(".subLink")
                               .addClass("subLink-white");
                    },
                    function() {            
                            $(this)
                                .removeClass("subMenuTDActive");
                                .children(".subLink")
                                .removeClass("subLink-white");
                    }
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

AKX's solution is correct.  Alternatively, you can do:

```
$(this).children(".subLink")
```